# significance of variable and function names being the same?

Tags: javascript, var

In some javascript code I'm seeing variables referencing functions with the same name, eg:

```
var Automobile = function Automobile() {
  this.someProperty = 1;
}
```

What's the purpose of that vs `var Automobile = function() {...}`

or even:

`var Automobile = function AnythingBesidesAutomobile() {...}`?

Debugging aid, possibly?

Comment: to provide different names inside and outside the function for debugging and recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing a local name for a function created in a function instantiation makes it possible for the function to refer to itself independently of any external (closure) variable. Consider:

```
var foo = function() {
  // do something
  setTimeout(foo, 1000);
};

setTimeout(foo, 1000);

foo = 23;
```

Because the code inside the function relies on the external symbol "foo" to access itself, the thing will fail after the first timeout. However:

```
var foo = function foo() {
  // do something
  setTimeout(foo, 1000);
};

setTimeout(foo, 1000);

foo = 23;
```

Now it'll work, because "foo" inside the function refers to the name given after the `function` keyword, not the "foo" in the enclosing scope.

You're also right about it being a debugging aid.  If you're setting up event handlers for example (please excuse the jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  // do all sorts of complicated stuff
});
```

It's nice to have a name show up in stack traces when things go wrong:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function buttonClickHandler() {
  // ...
});
```

Finally, [this used to be problematic due to bugs](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/), but I think a lot of that has been smoothed out in newer JavaScript runtime environments.

Comment: These answers all make sense, but I'm still curious if there's an important reason for giving the function and the variable the same name?  If you name the function you'd still see it in the call stack, so that makes sense, but as for giving it the same name as the variable?  Not sure what the reasoning is.

Comment: @larryq it's purely a matter of style and preference. However, if a name is given to the function (that is, a name *after* the `function` keyword), then that should be used inside the function for recursive references. It would be bad form to do otherwise except in some really bizarre circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

There's very little point to your first example (although there *can* be times when you want that), where the names are the same; a function *declaration* would normally (but not always) be more appropriate there:

```
function Automobile() {
  this.someProperty = 1;
}
```

Your second example makes a bit more sense, as the variable name and function name are different.

In either case, what you have there is called a *named function expression*. It creates a function with a true name (the one after the keyword `function`), at the point in step-by-step code where it appears, and also assigns a reference to that function to the given variable. The function's actual name is not added to the scope in which the expression appears but does exist within the function itself; the variable name, of course, exists in the scope in which the expression appears.

So why would you do your first example? Function *declarations* are not part of the step-by-step code. They cannot appear within control flow blocks (e.g., not within an `if` or similar), and they happen when the context in which they exist is created, before any step-by-step code is run. Sometimes you want to wait until the step-by-step execution reaches that point, in which case you use a function expression (a named one, in your case).

Side note: IE8 and earlier [really mess up](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) named function expressions, to the point where you should avoid using them in any case that may need to run on IE8 and earlier. This bug is fixed in IE9 and higher, and doesn't exist in current versions of other browsers. (*Older* versions of some other browsers had [different] issues with named function expressions, but not for years.)